# How to split a string in SQL and display that value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column (Col A) with a value that goes like this:

```
ThisValue=The Value;DateFrom=01/01/01;Regulated=No;
```

I want to select only `The Value` (From Col A) and have it displayed in a subquery.

So far I've tried to use `REPLACE`, but have had a hard time getting it to work inside a `select` statement.

Comment: Ouch. If you have any control over the database you need to fix this. You have a nightmare going on here. You are effectively storing an entire row in a single column. This is in serious need of normalization.

Comment: @SeanLange Now you feel my pain. I'm with you 100%

Comment: I'm having the hardest time trying to match the expression "ThisValue=" in order to parse what follows after it up till the delimiter ';'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`.

**QUERY**

```
declare @str as varchar(50)

set @str = 'ThisValue=The Value;DateFrom=01/01/01;Regulated=No;'

select substring(@str,charindex('=',@str,1)+1,
       ((charindex(';',@str,1))-(charindex('=',@str,1))-1));
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfab1/96)

Comment: is there a way I can do this without declaring a varable? In one subquery I want to select the value inside "ThisValue=The Value;" but in another subquery I would want to select the value inside "Regulated=no;"

Comment: so for example:

In one subquery I would want only to select "The Value" 
In another subquery I would want to only select "01/01/01"

Comment: Instead of a variable you can use a column_name also

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to have a splitter. My favorite is the one found here from Jeff Moden. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Some people don't like that one because it has a limit of varchar(8000). I have never needed to parse any delimited strings anywhere near that long so it has always been fine for me.

For a deeper look at splitters with a number of different options you can check out this article. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

```
declare @Something varchar(100) = 'ThisValue=The Value;DateFrom=01/01/01;Regulated=No;'

select max(case when y.ItemNumber = 1 then y.Item end) as DataName
    , max(case when y.ItemNumber = 2 then y.Item end) as DataValue
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Something, ';') x
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(x.Item, '=') y
where x.Item > '' --This eliminates the trailing semicolon
group by x.ItemNumber
order by x.ItemNumber
```